# Why do I see the postgres process when I run top although it is running only inside Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a Docker instance running Postgres and Postgres is not installed on the host machine.
However, if I run top on the host machine I can see several process Postgres.
Can you please explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers share the kernel from the host OS, so when running `top`  on the host machine, you'll see processes running on the containers in addition to those running on the host.

[image]

Source of image: Docker